# How to handle credit

Tags: workflow

How do you organise and remember all the people that helped in the project?
Do you simply have an excel sheet with the names and what the person did?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds a lot like you've answered your own question. I's suggest a cloud based spreadsheet to allow people to collaborate on it, so if say, your props person wanted to thank people for lending stuff they could add them to the list.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good idea to make it cloud based!

Answer (score 2):

Paperwork is important.  Beyond a simple Excel spreadsheet, you should have appropriate releases from everyone involved in your project.  Depending on your jurisdiction, it is likely that you can't make commercial use of someone's likeness without their consent, and if they decide they don't like your project for some reason they could force it to be taken down until you can edit them out of it without a release.

Similarly, for crew, by default, copyright sits with the person producing the work in most jurisdictions, unless there is an agreement otherwise or there is an employee relationship.  You need agreements with everyone from the project and you need to keep these organized so you can present them if necessary.

Yes, having a master list somewhere like Excel or in a text file is helpful for being able to more quickly add them to the credits, but you need far more than just a simple list of names to properly document a project.

Comment: Thank you. For me, this question was only about how you keep so many people in mind without reading all 200 contracts to figure it out again :)

Comment: Fair enough.  The answer will still probably help others as a lot of people go in naive to the need for releases.  Glad you knew about that already.

Comment: @Timothy Lukas H. If you have a 200 people crew... Some of them **should** be lawyers and administrative personnel... Take a look at the end credits of a movie and you will see them.